# How to update from Ubuntu 14.04.3 to 14.04.4

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

3 months ago I installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 with kernel 3.19.
My current kernel version is 3.19.0-49-generic

As I have a new DELL Precision 5510 laptop with Intel skylake technology some features work only with the new kernel 4

Therefore I've been waiting for Ubuntu 14.04.4 with kernel 4.2 which should be released in February 2016: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/LTS_Enablement_Stacks/
I've read that it was release some days ago: 11. Februar 2016

But it seems this point release isn't installed automatically with the regular system updates. How can I migrate/update to this new release without risking some instability

Thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed by @Larry Greenwald and described [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Kernel.2BAC8-Support.A14.04.x_Ubuntu_Kernel_Support). To update the kernel you need to do it manually like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-wily
```

Comment: Isn't the "install-recommends" redundant?

Answer (score 5):

I've done several point upgrades in the 14.04.x series. The 'apt-get dist-upgrade' command will update most things, but not necessarily the kernel. A 'uname -a' after the upgrade (and subsequent reboot) will tell you.

If you still have a 3.19 series kernel, you can then do 'sudo apt-get install Linux-generic-lts-wily' to get the 4.2 kernel.

Answer (score 3):

> $ sudo apt-get update
>
> $ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

It has been released on 18-Feb-2016 and you don't need to do anything manually. It updates as if it is a regular update. In terms of Linux Kernel it does not update Linux Kernel. If you want to update Linux kernel you have to do it manually. I hope this answers your query.

Answer (score 0):

simple way is to use **do-release-upgrade** command

i.e $> do-release-upgrade

this will search for the latest ubuntu release and install it on your machine

---